# How to not download new version of jar with buildr?

Tags: maven, buildr

For example if I have transitive('xxx:xxx:jar:1.4-SNAPSHOT') in artifacts.rb I don't want that when I run buildr to recive new version of 1.4-SNAPSHOT.

For buildr 1.4.0 no new version was download when I run buildr, but with buildr 1.4.4 it download new version if exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of making a dependency as a SNAPSHOT dependency is for it to be updated when changed.

As to why buildr-1.4.4 downloads SNAPSHOT updates and 1.4.0 does not, this was introduced in buildr-1.4.2 as per [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BUILDR-212).

You could run buildr in `offline` mode `(-o`) so that it does not download any updates.